# Stripe client integration doesn't redirect after first click event

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe client only integration in Angular2+ project following these steps:

[Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client)

The onClick implementation is working fine, but for some reason the click event redirects me only when I clicked twice, even though the console.log is working on the first one.

> **HTML**

```
<button id="checkout-button" role="link" (click)="onClick($event)">
    Checkout
</button>
```

> **.ts**

```
onClick() {
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_...');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            items: [{ sku: 'sku_...', quantity: 1 }],
            successUrl: 'https://your-website.com/success',
            cancelUrl: 'https://your-website.com/canceled',
        })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                    displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because at the first click, you are adding `addEventListener`. So when you click the second time, then your event handler is run.

In addition, it is not good to use `document.getElementById`. You can use [TemplateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef):

```
<button      
  role="link"
  (click)="onClick()"
  #checkout_button
>
  CheckoutButton Sku
</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('checkout_button') myEl: ElementRef;

constructor() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myEl.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: Just removed adding event listener, it's not even needed having Angular (click). Didn't look at it thoroughly at first because the code was generated by stripe dashboard. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @RamanHaivaronski You are welcome! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Had the same problem in a completely different framework (rails). Great answer + explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
```

You do not need to bind another event handler.

```
(click)="onClick($event)"
```

This part binds an event listener to the button. In onClick you do an another bind every time when button is clicked. This is why it works only for the second time.